# ordering non-decreasing functions then adding them in R

Tags: r, function, sorting, rstudio, array-merge

Need help with basic R function:

Firstly order non-decreasing sequence from 4 different sequences and then order those 4 sequences into one.

Im totally green in programing so please make it the simplest way possible.

Edit1: puting some input data as required

```
A={3,2,1,2}
B={6,7,5,8}
C={12,11,9,10}
D={65,43,76,13}
```

I would like it to first order each sequence, so

```
A={1,2,2,3}
B={5,6,7,8}
C={9,10,11,12}
D={13,43,65,76}
```

and then to merge it

```
ABCD={1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,43,65,76}
```

Comment: You should read some basic R documentation, because you don't seem to even know how to create a sequence of numbers (a "vector" in R-speak).

Comment: You may find [this tutorial on vectors in R](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector) and [this tutorial on functions in R](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function that takes vectors A, B, C, and D and input and outputs a sorted version of them, you can try:

```
sortAll <- function(A, B, C, D) sort(c(A, B, C, D))
```

And then you can run it with something like:

```
A <- c(1,2,2,3)
B <- c(5,6,7,8)
C <- c(9,10,11,12)
D <- c(13,43,65,76)
sortAll(A, B, C, D)
# [1]  1  2  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 43 65 76
```

If you wanted to write a function that combined and sorted any number of inputs, you could try:

```
sortAll <- function(...) sort(unlist(list(...)))
sortAll(A, B, C, D)
# [1]  1  2  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 43 65 76
sortAll(A)
# [1] 1 2 2 3
```